# Asynchronous Python: Reading multiple urls from a synchronous library

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm using `python-twitter` which isn't an asynchronous library and writing these to Django models. What I need to do for the sake of speed is read `n` batches of `100` `user_id`s at once. So:

`[[1234, 4352, 12542, ...], [2342, 124124, 235235, 1249, ...], ...]`

Each of these has to hit something like `api.twitter.com/users/lookup.json`.

I've tried to use something like this, but it seems to run synchronously:

```
await asyncio.gather(*[sync_users(user, api, batch) for batch in batches], return_exceptions=False)
```

I've also tried wrapping the synchronous library calls, but that also seems to run synchronously. How can I send out all of the username lookup requests at once?

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
results = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, api.UsersLookup(user_id=batch, include_entities=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling in a batch, Try something like this

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def get_user(user_id):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        print('calling')
        async with session.get("http://httpbin.org/headers") as response:
            print('getting response')
            response = await response.read()
            print(response)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = []
users = [1,2,3,4]  # a list of user ids
for user_id in users:
    tasks.append(asyncio.ensure_future(get_user(user_id)))

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))
```